# Use scopePublished() method in model from a controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method in my model :

```
public function scopePublished($query)
{
    return $query->where('status', 'PUBLISHED')
                 ->where('date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))
                 ->orderBy('date', 'DESC');
}
```

This method will be used in several places to retrieve published articles.

But, now, I'm in my controller and I would like use this function. How I do? I start in Laravel (and OOP).

I try this :

`$query = Article::paginate(8)`

`scopePublished($query)`

Can you explain to me? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to paginate published articles. So you can do this.

```
$query = Article::published()->paginate(8)
```

For more information take a look at `Local Scopes` under [Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: Hmmmmm! Okay ! `Scope` isn't necessary! Laravel is definitely amazing.

Comment: Can be apply published() scope on all queries globally without applying for each query in controller?

Answer (score 0):

Scopes are used as a part of the query without appending the word `scope`. In your case you can use it like so

```
$articles = Article::published()->paginate(8);
```

Check out the official doc for more information on local and global scopes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes